# setRetainInstance fragment with UI Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

Ok, I created a `Fragment` with some UI (couple textboxes and stuff) and I used `setRetainInstance` since Im running an `AsyncTask` to query a server (*request can only be sent once*) and I need the result of the `AsyncTask`. So my question is:
Is it wrong to retain the whole fragment with the UI? I saw couple examples where people use an extra `Fragment` to use the `setRetainInstance` but.. is there anything wrong not using that extra one??
If there is an issue with using the `setRetainInstance` why is that? Couldn't find any info in the documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use `setRetainInstance(true)`, your Fragment will still recreate its views when you rotate (you will get a call to `onDestroyView` and then `onCreateView`). As long as you don't keep references to views past `onDestroyView`, there will not be any leaks of the old Activity. The best approach would be to explicitly null the references in `onDestroyView`, but your code in `onCreateView` would generally overwrite those references anyway.

There are many examples online (including some official ones) where people use a separate fragment (without a view) to retain data. Assuming what I said above is correct, then this is unnecessary (for the sake of preventing leaks). In many cases, you may end up with cleaner code/architecture if you use a separate fragment whose responsibility is just to handle the data and not worry about the UI.

You can check to see if you are leaking Activity contexts after rotating by [using Eclipse MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Answer (score -1):

If you are locking your orientation then you should be fine. Otherwise you can end up with memory leaks if you retain widgets that are associated with a particular activity instance.

Comment: but arent the widgets associated with the Fragment? maybe I missunderstood how Fragments work.

Comment: Even if the orientation is locked, this could be problematic. Android re-creates the view for any configuration change. Whereas a configuration change could be a display rotation (the usual case), language change, keyboard attach/detach and others. Taking care of the screen rotation does not solve the whole problem.